# Using inherited process model for existing collection on Azure DevOps Server 2019

Tags: tfs-process-template, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2019

With Azure DevOps Server 2019 RC it is possible to enable inherited process model on new collections (see [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/release-notes/azuredevops2019#process-inheritance-on-new-collections)). Is there any way to use the inherited process model also for existing collections, where no customization on the process was made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inherited process model is currently only supported for new collections created with Azure DevOps Server 2019 and not for existing collections.

See [this Developer Community entry](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/614232/bring-inherited-process-to-existing-projects-for-a.html) which asks for it.

Comment: What is the link to the Developer Community entry? I didn't come through on your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is it: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365391/allow-for-updating-process-templates-on-existing-p.html

Comment: Current Developer Community entry is: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/614232/bring-inherited-process-to-existing-projects-for-a.html

Answer (score 0):

I added a set of comments on how I hacked my way from an existing XML collection with a set of Projects to the Inherited type.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/614232/bring-inherited-process-to-existing-projects-for-a.html

Working as long as a vanilla workflow is applied to an existing XML collection before doing the voodoo thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer for your question but we recently had the same task and I want to share how we handled this. We also wanted to move to the inherited model and we did not want to do any hacking. So we decided to create a new Collection on our Azure Devops Server 2020 with the inherited model and also migrate our tfvc repository to git.

1. Create the new Collection. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/manage-project-collections?view=azure-devops-2020)
2. [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) to create a local repository from our tfvc repository and push it
3. [azure-devops-migration-tools](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools) to copy all work items from the old collection to the new collection

   - In the old collection add the `ReflectedWorkItemId` for every WorkItem [look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/import-process/customize-process?view=azure-devops)
   - In the new collection add the `ReflectedWorkItemId` for every WorkItem by using the process editor
   - *Pro-Tip: create a full backup of the new collection to revert to this state easily. I had multiple try-error-restores.*
   - You can't migrate shared steps or shared parameters like this, because you can't edit these work item types in the new collection. There is a [workaround](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/518#issuecomment-690945677)
   - We used the `WorkItemTrackingProcessor` to migrate all Epics/Features/Product Backlog Items/Bugs/Tasks/Test Cases. Then the same processor but with the mentioned workaround for Shared Steps and Shared Parameters.
   - This processor also migrates the Iterations and Area Paths
   - Finally we used the `TestPlansAndSuitesMigration` to migrate the Test Plans and Suites
   - For speeding up the migration, you can chunk the work items (for example by date or id) and start the migration multiple times.
4. Our build and release pipelines + task groups were migrated manually by import and export

   - We migrated the variable groups by using the API
5. The teams were created manually and we added the default area paths also by hand